# Imap FetchError Yahoomail

Tags: python, imap, yahoo-mail

I am trying to fetch email from Yahoo mail.

```
msg = imap.fetch(str(fromMail[-1]), "(RFC822)")
```

When the above code it throws the following error but the the same is working for Gmail. Any clue what need to be changed for Yahoo mail.

```
imaplib.IMAP4.error: FETCH command error: BAD [b'[CLIENTBUG] FETCH Command arguments invalid']
```

Comment: Turn on imaplib debugging and see what you’re actually sending.  Are you sure fromMail[-1] is a number?

Comment: Yes it’s a number I verified

Comment: So, what did your imaplib trace look like just before you got the error?